# recv function from winsock.h, i don't understand how it works

Tags: c++, pointers, winsock2

I'm a beginner. The function requests the following parameters:

```
int recv(
  [in]  SOCKET s,
  [out] char   *buf,
  [in]  int    len,
  [in]  int    flags
);
```

The second parameter requests me to pass the address of a buffer, but in a video i'm watching, the guy passes the buffer by value, and as far as i know by doing this the function won't be able to modify the buffer, but for some reason it accepts the parameter anyway. Why?

This is the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VlUO6ERf1TQ&t=361s

This is the piece of code he writes:

```
int bytes = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        //Accept client request
        new_wsocket = accept(wsocket, (SOCKADDR *)&server, &server_len);
        if (new_wsocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
        {
            std::cout << "The socket is invalid";
        }

        //Read request
        char buff[30720] = { 0 };
        bytes = recv(new_wsocket, buff, BUFFER_SIZE, 0);
    }
```

---

Answer (score 2):

In various contexts (including when passed as a function parameter), a C-style array that is referred to by just its name alone will *decay* into a pointer to its 1st element.

See: [What is array-to-pointer conversion aka. decay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/)

So, in this situation, this code:

```cpp
char buff[30720] = { 0 };
bytes = recv(..., buff, ...);
```

Is functionally identical to this code:

```cpp
char buff[30720] = { 0 };
bytes = recv(..., &buff[0], ...);
```

---

On a side note: you have a `BUFFER_SIZE` constant defined, which you are passing to `recv()` as the size of the array that it reads into, but you are not using that same constant when declaring the array itself.  To help keep things consistent, you should either:

- declare the array using the constant:

```cpp
char buff[BUFFER_SIZE] = { 0 };
```

- use `sizeof()` instead of the constant:

```cpp
bytes = recv(..., buff, sizeof(buff), ...);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, i didn't know that, i saw the first comment you posted and i was already reading exactly that question you just linked. There's still a lot i have to know.